# Efficient 2D cutting algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to design a program for a machine that mills out parts of blocks of aluminum. The parts are 2D. The time it takes to mill each part is fairly extensive.

I'm looking for an algorithm to find a solution to mill out these parts in minimal time. The machine removes aluminum away from the block to construct the final shape so the possible mill paths are almost unlimited. Can anyone point me in the right direction or propose a solution to this problem? I don't know if such an algorithm exists.

Since I need to implement this algorithm myself, there is a tradeoff between the complexity of the algorithm and ease of implementation.

Update: I added an example shape below. The part with diagonal lines is the final shape and the dotted rectangle is the starting aluminum block. The machine needs to remove all of the aluminum with the exception of the diagonal area.

[image]

Comment: Does the machine have an API or something that you can link to?

Comment: Can the parts make a periodic shape when put together? You can halve the cutting time if yes. Can you show if it is a simple shape?

Comment: Yes, I can program the machine through the API. I'm just looking for a general algorithm that I can implement.

Comment: Ok, I've added an example shape to help illustrate the problem.

Comment: Do you know that entire companies exist that do nothing but develop sheet metal cutting software? It will take you a lot of time and effort to outdo them. No general theory of this cutting business exist. What they offer in the marketplace seems to be a combination of lots of brute force and lots of heuristics. Perhaps buying a commercial solution would be cost-effective for your company.

Comment: cnc machines do this stuff all day long. you might want to look into that market sector.

Comment: does it cut like a blade, or does it grind the material off? you've provided very meager details about how it works.

Comment: It's a grinder. It can mill off aluminum not cut.

Comment: Yep. It's a milling tool.

Comment: Then zim-zam's answer is more relevant for you.

Comment: Does it need to mill off all the non-hatched material? Can it just mill along the contour so that the unused material falls off? If the latter is not true then perhaps Zim-Zam's answer is what you need. Still, packing your parts more tightly will be the most significant saving factor, as it reduces both the amount of waste material and the time needed to remove it. Optimizing the cutter path will also contribute but probably not as much.

Comment: Yes, it must mill off all the non-hatched material.

Comment: This is a traveling salesman type problem with infinite nodes. As such ist not possible to solve this problem. However that does not mean you can not do better and tiis is a special case, just as loong as you do one continuous path that never mills empty then your at the near optimal line. Anyway this is graph theory stuff consider each cornera node and then do a visit each node one loop. In this case once you optimize the cutting out of the pocket your near optimal.

Answer (score 3):

i would think this is way more complex than you are describing.  there are likely constraints on the quality of the final cut, on the speed of the cut (depending on the volume you are removing), whether or not you can change bits, on how material can be clamped, etc.

but just taking your request at face value, i would suggest:

- following the outline to cut the shape.
- identify remaining material and use raster scans (side to side, shifting down at each end by the bit width) to eat away the material

that gives you a decent finish (the outline is a single cut so only one joint, which can be at a corner) and reasonable speed (you're trying to minimize time spent not cutting, which will only be when moving from one scan area to another).